# How to open Whatsapp group by clicking a button and getting its contact in a listview in android?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

How to open any Whats App group at the click of a button and then get all the contact numbers in it in a list view?
I am trying to open a group in whats app with the help of given code but when i click on this button nothing is showing.

```
    Intent intentWhatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String url = "https://chat.whatsapp.com/<link>";
    intentWhatsapp.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    intentWhatsapp.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(intentWhatsapp);
```

I think there can be two forms.
1- Either the WhatsApp group whose contacts we want to get is present in the WhatsApp in our mobile and we are also added as a member in this WhatsApp group.
2- We have the link of any WhatsApp group with the help of which we can get its contacts without being added to that group.
How to solve this I don't have any specific information but if anyone can guide I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

> Opening a WhatsApp group using a link and extracting contact numbers from it programmatically is not straightforward due to privacy and security considerations. WhatsApp's API does not expose such features, and attempting to manipulate it programmatically may violate their terms of service.

Additionally, the code you provided is used to open a WhatsApp group using its invite link, but it won't provide access to the group members or their contact information.

Always ensure that your app's functionality aligns with the terms of service of the platforms you are integrating with, and respect user privacy and consent.

Comment: I have checked many apps on google play store which are messaging on whatsapp called bulk message sender. This app allows its user to extract WhatsApp group numbers.

Comment: These apps that I have mentioned, if a user is a member of a WhatsApp group, allow them to extract all the numbers of the group with one click.